# Function that is continuous defined as an integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$. Then show that $g(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(y-x)}{1+y^{2}} \mathrm{d}y$ is a continuous function. I know that $\left| g(x) - g(x_{0}) \right| = \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(y-x) - f(y-x_{0})}{1+y^{2}} dy \right|$, but I can't seem to get a bound for it.

Comment: Say, $f$ is continuous with $\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}<\infty$, you know that $\dfrac{f(y-x)-f(y-x_{0})}{1+y^{2}}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow x_{0}$. Now you appeal to Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem since $\left|\dfrac{f(y-x)-f(y-x_{0})}{1+y^{2}}\right|\leq\dfrac{2\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}}{1+y^{2}}\in L^{1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $\varphi\in C_{00}$ and we let 
\begin{align*}
h(x)=\int\dfrac{\varphi(y-x)}{1+y^{2}}dy,
\end{align*}
then 
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{\varphi(y-x)}{1+y^{2}}\right|\leq\|\varphi\|_{L^{\infty}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1+y^{2}}\in L^{1},
\end{align*}
and hence we can apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem to show that $h$ is continuous.

Now we let $\varphi_{n}\in C_{00}$ be such that $\|f-\varphi_{n}\|_{L^{1}}<1/n$ and 
\begin{align*}
h_{n}(x)=\int\dfrac{\varphi_{n}(y-x)}{1+y^{2}}dy.
\end{align*}
We see that
\begin{align*}
|g(x)-h_{n}(x)|&=\left|\int\dfrac{f(y-x)-\varphi_{n}(y-x)}{1+y^{2}}dy\right|\\
&\leq\int\dfrac{1}{1+y^{2}}\cdot|f(y-x)-\varphi_{n}(y-x)|dy\\
&\leq\int|f(y-x)-\varphi_{n}(y-x)|dy\\
&=\int|f(z)-\varphi_{n}(z)|dz\\
&=\|f-\varphi_{n}\|_{L^{1}},
\end{align*}
we deduce that
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|g(x)-h_{n}(x)|\leq\|f-h_{n}\|_{L^{1}}<1/n,
\end{align*}
this means that the continuous functions $h_{n}$ converge uniformly to $g$, and hence $g$ must be continuous.

Comment: Why is $h_{n}$ continuous? That is, why does DCT give continuity?

Comment: As you can move $x\rightarrow x_{0}$ inside the integral with $x_{0}$ fixed.

Comment: We are showing that $\frac{\phi_{n}(y-x)}{1+y^{2}}$ is dominated so its limit is integrable but why does that yield continuity since we are integrating wrt to $y$.

Comment: Forget about the $n$ and you are to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\displaystyle\int\cdots=\int\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\cdots$. So you need an upper bound, as I noted that $\|\varphi\|_{L^{\infty}}1/(1+y^{2})$ is a good one.

Comment: Okay but this seems like an uncountable limit, because I thought in DCT we need a sequence of functions $\psi_{n} =  \phi(y-x_{0} \pm \frac{1}{n}) \rightarrow phi(y-x-{0})$. Then we can get sequences $\left| \int \frac{{\phi(y-x_{0}) \pm \frac{1}{n})- \phi(y-x_{0})}}
{1+y^{2}} dy\right| < \epsilon$

Comment: The trick is to switch the limit as the sequential characterization of limit, as appeal to Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem for that particular sequence, since the sequence is arbitrary chosen, it switches back to the uncountable limit, this is omitted in mostly of the real analysis books, I admit.

Comment: I see, so there are sequences that can converge from various directions and so we obtain the uncountable limit in that way.